# Generate a column script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to generate a script of specific table column. 
How i can do that?

SQL Server 2012 allow to generate a script of a single table but not a single column.

Comment: What are you asking for? `MyColumn int`?

Comment: What type of script you want to create?

Comment: Do you mean the script to **add a new column**?

Comment: I don't think you are asking for what you think you are asking for. The scripts you generage can `CREATE` a table, veiw, function, or a stored procedure. You can't make just a column. That would then be a one column table.

Comment: @Zane i'm looking to generate a create script i just want a column of the table not the complete table script.

Comment: Search sys.columns view?

Comment: Do you want to `SELECT` the data from that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in functionality to do this. In order to accomplish something like this, you would need to make a script that would go through the system tables to retrieve the information for the column then generate an ALTER TABLE [] ADD [] statement.

I do something like this with temp tables so you can see an example of what that might look like. I would note the code sample provided here is partially complete and updated whenever I encounter a corner case it doesn't cover already.

http://bigdatabigdave.info/archive/2013/03/08/scripting-create-table-statements-from-temp-table-definitions/

Comment: I'm not even sure that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: Just my best guess for what he's looking for. Not much to go on.